# /dev/random does not block

Tags: c, linux, unix, random, entropy

I am trying to gather true random numbers from /dev/random. Here is my simple code:

```
u_char buf[256];

memset(buf, 0, 256);

int dev = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);

int nbr = read(dev, buf, 100);

printf("Number of bytes returned : %d\n", nbr);
```

As you can see that i am asking for 100 random bytes but when i run this program i always get output in variable *nbr* in range of 15 to 30 which is understandable as /dev/random does not always have enough entropy but my expectation was that upon read(), /dev/random should block until it fills my buffer to 100 random bytes which does not occur in this case and program does not block. I read man pages for /dev/random. It says that

> When the entropy pool is **empty**, reads from /dev/random will block
>   until additional environmental noise is gathered.

Does this literally mean that /dev/random will only block when entropy pool is **empty** and will not block when it has any amount data whether or not it is less than the required bytes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try /dev/urandom if you want non-blocking ?

Comment: "I am trying to gather true random numbers from /dev/random." - You messed up here.

Comment: Just think of a number instead.

Comment: I do not want to use /dev/urandom. Lets say it is compulsion on me to use /dev/random/.

Comment: Maybe your hardware is recent enough so as to have a good enough random source. IIRC, some recent i7 processors have a machine instruction giving (physically) random numbers. With a recent enough kernel, that perhaps makes `/dev/random` never blocking. And the `random(4)` page mention a size of 256 bytes....

Comment: What's the problem?  Just keep reading until you get 100 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not special to `/dev/random`, that's just the behaviour of `read`. The parameter is a buffer size and `read` will return what's available up to that size.

Consider using a `FILE*` and `fread` instead to read one block of 100 bytes.

Comment: Yes this is one way of doing it but when does /dev/random blocks as man page says?

Comment: @JewelThief: I don't understand your question. `/dev/random` does block as the man page describes (to my knowledge).

Comment: @JewelThief read() blocks if no data is available until some data is available, even if this is less then requested (but more then 0). Also see Joe's answer and `man 3 read()`.

Answer (score 2):

In short, unless there's ***no*** data to be read, read will not block. It will always return the amount it could read or an error, even if that's less data than you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is reading 100 bytes from `/dev/random`. If you restart it with some manual action (e.g. typing the command, or simply the arrow-up key for bash), that manual action (sequence of keypresses) is feeding the entropy pool of `random(4)`. So you would never be in the blocking case.

And the semantics of the [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) syscall applied to `/dev/random` is that it will try to read some bytes. If at least one byte has been read, the `read(2)` syscall succeeds and does not block.

Also, as I commented, recent enough hardware and recent enough kernel has a good enough random source which might maje `random(4)` never block.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/random gets a data from SHA1(entropy_pool_data). SHA1 outputs only 20 bytes. It doesn't make sense to request more than 160 bits from /dev/random if you wish to obtain a truly random bits.